# BeautifulSoup parse XML namespaces

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have this script:

```
infile = open("t.gpx", "r")
contents = infile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')

wpts = soup.find_all('wpt')
names = soup.find_all('name')
texts = soup.find_all('text')
types = soup.find_all('type')
gnames = soup.find_all('groundspeak:name')
gplaced = soup.find_all('groundspeak:placed_by')
print()
for i in range(0, len(wpts)):
    print(names[i].get_text(), end=' ')
    print(texts[i].get_text(), end=' ')
    print(types[i].get_text(), end=' ')
    print(gnames[i].get_text(), end=' ')
    print(gplaced[i].get_text(), end='\n')
```

and input file t.gpx.

### [t.gpx](https://app.box.com/s/1qwjodkjakvensh78tjwq26qnqcbyjt5)

The first line of output:
      XX022421 jn32766 Geocache|Geocache jn32766 jn_mapotic

is OK, but second line is different than I expect.
      jn32766 ss_old_687 Geocache ss_old_687 roze

I expect XX027931 at the beginning.

What's wrong with my script?

Comment: You might want to post a snippet of your XML

Comment: yes a snippet would be great - then we re able to give you support